# Stuck at proof to show continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given, $f(x)= x - \left \lceil{x}\right \rceil  $.

I have to use sequential definition of continuity to find where it's continuous.

First i check at integer. Let $x=a, a\in \mathbb{Z}$. So, $f(a)=a$. We can find sequence $x_n$ converging to $a$. Given $\epsilon > 0 $. $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq k,  |x_n - a | < \epsilon$. or $x_n \in (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) $

To show $f(x_n) \to a$.
When $x \in (a-\epsilon, a ), f(x_n)= x_n - (a-1)$. When $x \in (a, a+ \epsilon), f(x_n)= x_n -a $

$x_n \to a$. so. $x_n -a \to x - a $ and $x_n -a +1 \to 1$.

I am stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not stuck, you are on the way to proving that there is indeed a discontinuity at each integer.

For example, let $a = 0$. Consider two sequences $x_n = \frac 1 n$ and $y_n = - \frac 1 n$. Both sequences tend to $0$. But $f(x_n) = \frac 1 n -1 \to -1$ and $f(y_n) = - \frac 1 n \to 0$. This precisely contradicts the definition of continuity of $f$ at $0$.

Comment: how do i arrive at contradiction and how to prove it is continuous for any real number which is not integer

Comment: 1) To observe that this is a contradiction, write down the definition of continuity with quantifiers. If $f$ was continuous, the existence of the sequence $x_n$ would imply $f(0) = -1$. The existence of $y_n$ would imply $f(0) = 0$. But $0 \neq -1$. 2) Near a non integer point, you should start by proving that $\lceil x \rceil$ is locally constant.

Comment: how do i find a sequence $x_n$ in $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ which converge to a. and how to prove it is continuous at non integer points

Comment: You probably already know that $x \mapsto x$ is a continuous function. Let $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$. To prove the continuity of $f$ at $a$, it is thus sufficient to prove the continuity at $a$ of $x \mapsto \lceil x \rceil$. In fact, you can even prove that this function is locally constant near $a$. For this, you must find $\delta > 0$ such that, for every $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$, $\lceil x \rceil = \lceil a \rceil$.

Comment: how to do this.,